# Loading API with jQuery and Ajax, its returning Object Object, can't figure out how to get it to display JSON data in the console or anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I'm calling an API with the following code and if all I get back is Object Object. I've tried a few different things, with no luck. I am getting jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 XHR finished loading: GET "url.to.api" in console. Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
url: "to API", // note, this doesn't end in JSON, but if I type the URL into my browser, I can view the JSON data

// Request headers
beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Subscription-Key", my key");
    },
})
.done(function (data) {
alert(data); // I changed this from a 'success' pop up to tell me it was working, but I can't display the data anywhere, so I tried in the box, and got object object
})
   .fail(function () {
  alert("error");
});
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to API's, there is no documentation on this one at all. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried console.log instead of alert? Also, you may want to add something like dataType : "application/json" in your object if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API URLs do not necessary need to end in JSON. If you view the API response through your browser and it is indeed in the JSON syntax, the API is likely to be outputting the result in JSON.

In that case, the ajax request will automatically parse the response from the API call to a javascript object, which is why it will show `[object Object]` when you do `alert(data)`.

To print out the contents of the javascript object as a string, you will simply need to stringify the object before alerting using the `JSON.stringify()` syntax as follows:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data)); // I changed this from a 'success' pop up to tell me it was working, but I can't display the data anywhere, so I tried in the box, and got object object
```